# Postgres prepared statement bind `now()`

Tags: postgresql

I have a prepared insert statement which has a placeholder for a date. I want to be able to insert a date provided by a user, or if it has not been provided fall back to inserting the current time using `now()`. Is it possible to bind the result of `now()` or do I need to use a second insert statement using `now()` directly in the statement rather than a placeholder?
For example, can I do this:

```sql
PREPARE my_statement AS 
INSERT INTO my_table (date_column) 
VALUES ($1);
EXECUTE my_statement (now());
```

or do I need to do this

```sql
PREPARE my_statement AS 
INSERT INTO my_table (date_column) 
VALUES (now);
EXECUTE my_statement;
```

Comment: You can pass `'now'` as value, however it sounds like you might rather want to make it explicit that you want to use a fallback: `COALESCE($1, now())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to bind the result of `now()`?

Yes. According to [the docs of the `EXECUTE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html), each of the parameters "*must be an expression yielding a value that is compatible with the data type of this parameter*". This allows arbitrary expressions, such as the `now()` function call, not just literal values.

Comment: ... but `current_date` would be more appropriate than `now()`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You mean because it's a date column? If it were a timestamp column, would you prefer `current_timestamp` over `now()`?

Comment: Yes, because OP said it was a `date`. `now()` and `current_timestamp` are equivalent, but I prefer the latter, because it is standard SQL.